# Add multiple drop down lists to ASP.NET form on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET form with one drop-down list. I want to have a "+" sign next to the list to allow the user to add another drop-down to the form, and so on, up to a maximum of 15 drop-downs. Ideally, this will be handled client-side, but I would also be open to a solution that involved a form post back. What is the best approach?

Comment: Please indicate approx. how many items in each dropdown - i.e. how big is your options universe?

Comment: There will be a couple hundred items in each dropdown.

Comment: What will the new drop-down lists contain? Will they be clones of the existing drop-down list or will they contain different options? If they options are different, how they be created?